# Mix debugger commands and ruby code evaluation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

I'm currently upgrading an old project from and old version of ruby(1.8.7)/rails(3.0) to 1.9.3/3.1 (as a stepping stone to newer versions).

I'm using gems `debugger` for 1.9.3 and `ruby-debug` for 1.8.7

When I run , I can run commands like `info variables` to get the list and values of all currently-scoped variables:

```
...
@current_phone = nil
@fields = {}
@global = {:source_type=>"pdf"}
@images = []
@index = {}
@lines = []
...
```

Also I can run arbitrary ruby code - a useful one I've been using is

```
File.open("/tmp/new_version", "w"){|f|f.write(@fields)}
```

which is useful for me to quickly compare between the old version and the new version using a file diff program.

Can I link these together so I can write to a file all the output of `info variables`? It would be sufficient if I could do

```
tempvar = info variables
```

or something along those lines, of course, but that gives

```
*** NameError Exception: undefined local variable or method `variables' for <ClassWhatever>
```

Comment: What debugger are you using?

Comment: @Jordan Gem 'debugger' for 1.9.3 and 'ruby-debug' for 1.8.7

Answer (score 1):

```
instance_variables.map { |v| [v, instance_variable_get(v)] }
```

Not exactly hash map, but you'll be good with it.

Comment: Show just instance_variables output

Comment: Ahh yes, you got arrays in some of your variables. Will fix answer now.